# Where should I store JSON file and fetch data in Next.JS whenever I need?

Tags: next.js, vercel

**Project:**

I am working on an E-commerce application and it has more than ***1,600 products*** and ***156 categories***.

**Problem:**

Initially, on the first product page, 30 products will be fetched (due to the page limitation), but on the left sidebar, I need filters that will be decided on the basis of **tags** of all **1,600 products**. So that's why I need all the products in the first fetch and then I will extract common **tags** by looping over all the products and immediately show them on the sidebar.

**What do I want?**

I am not sure but I think it would be the best solution if I generate a **JSON file** containing all the products and store it somewhere, where I can fetch just hitting the URL using REST API in **Next JS** (either in getServerSideProps or getStaticProps).

**Caveat:**

I tried by storing JSON file in **./public** directory in next js application, it worked in **localhost** but not in **vercel**.

**Here is the code I wrote for storing JSON file in **./public** directory:**

```
fs.writeFileSync("./public/products.json", JSON.stringify(products, null, 2));  //all 1,600 products
```

Comment: I see a redis tag but where are the 30 products you say you're fetching actually stored stack-wise?

Comment: so why don't you just `fetch` the file from the `public` directory?

Comment: @Nelloverflow I am fetching from the backend that gives only 30 products per page, but for getting all products I have to use the loop for each page and each page contains 30 products, so for 1600+ products I have to use more than 300 times I think.
Example: &per_page=30&page1

Comment: @IvanV. In vercel serverless function is giving an error and also it is non recommended approach to fetch data from local files 
error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './public/products.json'

Comment: I added a Redis tag because the only thing I know about redis is, it helps for caching data.... So that's why I thought that Redis may have a solution for my problem

Answer (score 1):

One solution it to fetch it directly from front-end (if the file is not too big) otherwise, for reading the file in `getServerSideProps` you will need a custom webpack configuration.

```js
//next.config.js
const path = require("path")
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    target: "serverless",
    future: {
        webpack5: true,
    },
    webpack: function (config, { dev, isServer }) {
        // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
        if (!isServer) {
            config.resolve.fallback.fs = false
        }
        // copy files you're interested in
        if (!dev) {
            config.plugins.push(
                new CopyPlugin({
                    patterns: [{ from: "content", to: "content" }],
                })
            )
        }

        return config
    },
}
```

Then you can create a utility function to get the file:

```js
export async function getStaticFile(file) {
    let basePath = process.cwd()
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        basePath = path.join(process.cwd(), ".next/server/chunks")
    }

    const filePath = path.join(basePath, `file`)
    const fileContent = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8")
    return fileContent
}
```

There is an open issue regarding this:
[Next.js API routes (and pages) should support reading files](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8251)

Comment: Is there any other resource for storing that file rather than local file ??

Comment: I would like to store in any external DB if it is possible, if possible then which one you will suggest ?

Comment: Use MongoDB it is the easiest one to work with.